# Django Admin login OperationalError at /admin/login/ (1044, "Access denied for user

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-admin, pythonanywhere

I'm using Django 1.10 with Python 3.5.2 on the PythonAnywhere web hosting platform and I am trying to login to the Admin site with my my Django superuser called adminuser but I am having this error,

```
OperationalError at /admin/login/ (1044, "Access denied for user adminuser
```

What can be the problem?

Comment: That looks like an error from your MySQL database. Your MySQL username and password are different from your Django user credentials. Check your `DATABASES` setting is correct.

Comment: Settings looks fine, user has all privileges to database, what else could it be? I even tried to make mysql username/password and Django username/admin password the same, but still same error.

Comment: Making the Django and MySQL username/passwords the same won't help, they are completely separate. It's tricky to help when the only information we have is '1044 Access denied'. Hope you get it working.

Comment: It's hosting error restarted MySQL fixed it., thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

reload the domain/url through the reload button in the Web tab, is the solution.

Comment: PythonAnywhere developer here -- I'm a bit confused.  What did you do to "restart" the MySQL server?  We don't have an interface for that, and I can't think of any way you could do it.

Comment: Oh I thought reloading the domain restarts MySQL. What happens when I reload? And is there a way to auto reload? Anyway that solved the issue, I'll reword the answer and Pythonanywhere is awesome by the way!

Comment: Ah, I see.  Reloading the website stops and then starts the process that's running your code, but not the MySQL server.  So you need to do it when you change the code so that the changes can be picked up.  You can do it programmatically by editing the WSGI file (the one linked from the "Web" tab).  We don't auto-reload because, while it's useful when people are coding their site, it's not what you want for sites that are live -- you don't want users of a production system getting served pages by a site where one file has been changed but related changes in another file haven't been saved yet.